# Is there a way to create multiple generic pass in iOS for apple wallet just by using swift and not using any server?

Tags: ios, swift, passkit, apple-wallet, pkpass

The application I am working on has a requirement for creating pass for each worker. Is there a way to create the same on front end?

Comment: In theory you can do this, but generating a pass requires cryptographic signing operations. To do this in your app would require you to include your signing keys in the app. This is not generally considered secure.

Comment: @Paulw11 okay and how can I include signing keys in the app, I mean what are the steps to create pass by including signing keys in the app?

Comment: You need to generate a certificate as described in the apple pass kit documentation. Then you would need to include that certificate and your private key as files in your bundle and then you would need to use cryptographic functions to generate the appropriate signatures, create a pass bundle on the file system and then pass that bundle to passkit to put the pass in the wallet.